# How to extract image from JSON response in iOS

Tags: ios, json, web-services, parsing

I am parsing JSON from a webService which gives me image , text , etc.The text can be extracted  , but how do I get the image out of it?

This is how the JSON response looks like.

```
[
 {  "photo": "23_841676772.jpg",
    "date": "2013-06-06 08:11:15",
    "tags": "",
    "ID_article": "1",
    "commentcount": "5"
 },
]
```

And I was trying to set it like this in tableView:cellForRow method which doesn't work.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict3 = [self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.blogImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[tempDict3 objectForKey:@"photo"]];
```

Comment: Do you get url from from jSON (photo key) ? If it is then you are doing it wrong way ..

Comment: do you have `23_841676772.jpg` in your resource?

Comment: yes where does 23_841676772.jpg reside .. ? All you are getting back is the image name + extension ..

Comment: Have "Url of image on server" as a value for **photo**, then download image in back - ground from that path.

Comment: Okay..Any sample code guys?....

Comment: sample code will depend on the location from where you have to download the image. Json response should send link of the image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702608/faster-way-to-load-an-image-from-a-url-and-display-it-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: It seems like you are getting a string as the image file. You have two alternatives, you either send the data to the client or send a url to download the image.

Answer (score 1):

**For extercating the Photo name from the JASON response you can use this code**

```
JSONResponse : [
 {  "photo": "23_841676772.jpg",
    "date": "2013-06-06 08:11:15",
    "tags": "",
    "ID_article": "1",
    "commentcount": "5"
 },
]
```

Make a Array object in `.h` file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray * photoNameData;
}
```

And in `.m` file

```
photoNameData =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * tmpAry = JSONResponse;
if (tmpAry.count !=0) {
        for (int i=0; i<tmpAry.count; i++) {
            NSMutableDictionary * tmpDictn = [tmpAry objectAtIndex:i];
            [photoNameData addObject:[tmpDictn objectForKey:@"photo"]];
        }
    }
```

**You can use the code below to download the image in document directory.**

```
for (int i=0; i<photoNameData.count; i++) {  //updated here

//First check that document directory contain image or not  
        NSString* tmpStr = [photoNameData objectAtIndex:i];  // used the photoNameData to get image name
        NSString* tmpImgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://www.my server.com/web_services/photos/",tmpStr];   //merge the image name and url
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documents = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* foofile = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpStr];
        BOOL imageExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];

//  if image not exist than download it
            if (!imageExists) {
                        NSLog(@"%@ not exist",tmpImgURL);
                        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpImgURL] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10.0];
                        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *err){
                            if (!err && data) {
                                //NSLog(@"data : %@",data);
                                NSString *finalPath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpStr];
                                NSLog(@"finalPath : %@",finalPath);
                                [data writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
                            }else{
                                NSLog(@"err : %@",err);
                            }
                        }];
                    }
}
```

And you can use this image using this code..

```
NSString* tmpStr = [photoNameData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  //get the image name from photoNameData
NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectoryPath, tmpStr]];
cell.blogImageView.image = image;
```

Comment: Well the first part of your answer doesn't provide image.I guess I will need to download the image...

Comment: First part of answer only work if you have image in your application bundle. but if you are getting the image from the server than the second part of answer will help. But remember that you need image URL not just its name.

Comment: http:// my server/web_services/photos/...this is the photos folder from my server..which contains all the images ...

Comment: than your `tmpImgURL` will be `my server/web_services/photos/23_841676772.jpg`

Comment: Check the update at `tmpImgURL`. Your URL will look something like that.

Comment: Add your image URL in `tmpImgURL` than second part will install image and you can use it in cell.

Comment: Use String concatenation to merge you image name and URL

Comment: Check my answer i have updated it with string concatenation and get the image name from array we created in first part of answer.

Comment: in my scenario my json is like that what can i do?                                                                                                              [
 {  "upload/photo": "23_841676772.jpg",
    "date": "2013-06-06 08:11:15",
    "tags": "",
    "ID_article": "1",
    "commentcount": "5"
 },
]

Answer (score 1):

I have used static json you can replace str with your json url.

```
NSString *Str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[{\"photo\": \"23_841676772.jpg\",\"date\":\"2013-06-06 08:11:15\",\"tags\": \"\",\"ID_article\": \"1\",\"commentcount\": \"5\"},{\"photo\": \"dfdgfdgd.jpg\",\"date\":\"2013-06-06 08:11:15\",\"tags\": \"\",\"ID_article\": \"1\",\"commentcount\": \"5\"}]"];


NSDictionary *catgDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[Str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];

for(NSDictionary *dict in catgDict)
{
    NSLog(@"dd: %@",dict);
    NSLog(@"Photo: %@",[dict valueForKey:@"photo"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ask your web service team to add another tag as "image_url" to your response so that you can convert the image url to image. If they say we can't give it for security reason, then the only option left is hard code the path and append the "image name" to it so that you will have complete url of image and now you can convert it into image.